# Is (!~index) faster than (index === -1)?

Tags: javascript, performance, bitwise-operators

Every so often I run across someone using `(!~val)` instead of `(val === -1)` in situations where -1 is returned from a function (e.g. `indexOf()`).

To me, the logical NOT + bitwise NOT statement seems horribly unreadable when compared to the -1 comparison. Is there enough of a speed difference to warrant using one over the other?  Or if not speed, some other reason that I'm missing to use a bitwise NOT instead of === ?

(Aplologies in advance if this is a dup., but I couldn't find an answer to this exact question. Searching for "!~" doesn't quite work in SO or Google)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are definitely not the same.

The bitwise conversion will do an implicit type coercion. The === operator checks for type equality.

So these these two can give completely different results.

```
var val = "-1";

(!~val) // true
(val === -1)  // false
```

In a situation like this I think the intent and correctness of the comparison far outweighs any performance consideration. Decide what exactly you want to compare and use the right comparison for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the type coercion. Wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a *meaningful* performance difference? Likely not, but it depends *entirely* on the VM.

You can always find out using something like http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 0):

### Be [pragmatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pragmatic_Programmer), go for readability

Both are *f@$# off* fast.

If your script has performance issues it **definitely won't boil down to this boolean check**. But as others have stated these two are not (completely) the same.